# 9patch keep seeing the balck lines

Tags: android, layout, nine-patch

I try to make an image strechable with 9patch. But if I make a 9.png image and use it, I see the black lines I drew in 9patch.

[image: 9patch problem]

How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: I guess, You have not put that lines correctly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're creating the 9-patch using a bitmap editor (e.g. like Gimp) then you have to make sure the 1 pixel border surrounding the image is completely transparent except for the black 9-patch markers.

Comment: I'm using the draw9patch application from SDK /tools directory. I don't understand what you say.

Comment: I meant just your final 9 patch image, but Adil Soomro has it right - your lines are incorrect.

You can only have continuous marker lines (i.e. your split top line is wrong) and your padding lines (right and bottom) should enclose the left/top lines if you want to avoid some very weird effects.

The Android documentation on this is very clear.

Comment: Correction: a 9-patch is allowed to have multiple stretchable areas i.e. the top and left lines do not need to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in xml

```
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:divider="#00000000" 
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
    android:fadingEdge="none" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

To be much clearer, Always the bottom and right marker lines (#000000 - black) should not be broken and should be one continuous straight line. Your bottom and right areas are the fill areas. So this is how 9 patch in android works.